# Possibly a glitch or bug while putting troops in war cc

Tags: clash-of-clans

M daily player of COC and taking part in war too.. Today i noticed while filling my clan's castle with level 3 dragons that if i will put level 3 drag and if i will check back then i will see there are level 4 dragons. I don't know why its showing level 4 when i put level 3..Its not like that some one put but i just checked back after putting drag in cc. So is it any glitch or bug? and what will come if some one will attack them?

I will check replies when war will start and share but just curious to share or to ask..Hope i won't get any negative marks for asking this question as m always getting negative marks no matter whatever i ask so please be human and help or solve my query..

```
          Thank you
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would advise you to check your clan perks. Since the last update, clans earn experience while warring. The reward for a clan reaching level 5 is their cc troops being upgraded by one level.

Comment: Yes as my clan is level 5 and soon it will be level 6. and if this is because this then thank you much..:)